# How to instantiate Spring boot Repository under standalone evironment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

all,

I am using spring boot in my project. It is great. 
My project has a part of it that operates on database periodically(with a timer), and not in response to a http request.
It's periodically queries a sensor(a lot of sensors) and collects temperature readouts, and stores the readouts into database.
Before storing it into database, the readout number is compared to a warning threshold to test if a warning should be generated.

The threshold number is to be queried(complicated) out from database, too.
I have a ThresholdRepository extending JPAResository for this query, so I want to use it in this scenario.

My question is: Could I use @Autowire to make spring boot generate ThresholdRepository instance for me? If not, how to instantiate ThresholdRepository in this timer thread?

I find some code at :http://www.yjs001.cn/java/spring/33161827667841434606.html

unfortunately, the code is outdated and `RepositoryMetadata` has no `getDomainClass` and I don't know which alternative should be used.
Please someone help me out.

Any recommendation is appreciated.

The repository I mentioned is as following:

`public interface ThresholdInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<ThresholdInfo, Long> {
    ThresholdInfo findOneByGatewayIdAndNodeAddrAndChannel(Long gatewayId, Byte nodeAddr, Byte channel);
    List<ThresholdInfo> findByGatewayId(Long gatewayId);
}`

It's short, but does a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can,

You have to @EnableJpaRepositories for your repositories to become a bean.

Then, to be able to autowire it, your TimerTask needs to be a Spring Bean as well. You could use spring-tasks https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}

@Component
public class UpdateTask {
    @Autowired 
    ThresholdInfoRepository thresholdInfoRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = ...)
    public void updateSensor() {
        thresholdInfoRepository.find(...)
        readoutRepository.save(...);
    }
}
```

Spring boot will start a timer thread to execute your scheduled method.

Comment: thank you so much. This is just what I needed to know.